# Extract / filter data from a map based on elements in Java/Grails

Tags: java, grails, arraylist

I have a map see below (orginalList), this coming from an oracle database, and contains elements

```
def orginalList = 
[
    [info:"F123",brand:"BMW",dID:3,price:40000],
    [info:"F100",brand:"BMW",dID:3,price:40000], 
    [info:"F200",brand:"BMW",dID:3,price:40000], 
    [info:"C344",brand:"mercedes",dID:5,price:50000], 
    [info:"C354",brand:"mercedes",dID:5,price:50000], 
    [info:"D355",brand:"Opel",dID:7,price:30000]
 ]
```

I would to filter this list and put the result into a new list like the list below (newList) as you can see, the BMW showing three times, mercedes two times, Opel one time and have the same **dID**, so I would like to put BMW into one row on the basis of **dID** , and one row for two mercedes and one row for the Opel. and the count the total, like below:

```
def newList =[['infos':'F123_F100_F200', 'brand':'BMW', 'dID':3, 'price':40000, 'total':3], ['infos':'C344_C354', 'brand':'mercedes', 'dID':5, 'price':50000, 'total':2], ['infos':'D355', 'brand':'Opel', 'dID':7, 'price':30000, 'total':1]]
```

I tried some thing like the below but this doesnt give the result I want:

```
List<Export> result = []
        for (Object y : GetUniqueValues(orginalList.dID)){

               Export export = new InvoiceExport()
               export.dID = y
               result << export
        }

 public static ArrayList GetUniqueValues(Collection values)
    {
        return new ArrayList(new HashSet(values));
    }
```

Who can help and please with example. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @michal-szulc said, what you posted as the input list is actually a `Map`. If you were to evaluate `originalList` in Groovy you'd get:

```
[info:"D355",brand:"Opel",dID:7,price:30000]
```

Since the data came from a database query, most likely you have a `List<Map<String, Object>>` (list of maps). Like this:

```
def orginalList = 
    [
        [info:"F123",brand:"BMW",dID:3,price:40000],
        [info:"F100",brand:"BMW",dID:3,price:40000], 
        [info:"F200",brand:"BMW",dID:3,price:40000], 
        [info:"C344",brand:"mercedes",dID:5,price:50000], 
        [info:"C354",brand:"mercedes",dID:5,price:50000], 
        [info:"D355",brand:"Opel",dID:7,price:30000]
     ]
```

*That* makes sense. If that's the case, you can achieve what you're looking for using `groupBy(Closure)` and `collect(Closure)`:

```
orginalList.groupBy { it.dID }.collect { dID, maps ->
    def head = maps.head()

    [
        infos: maps*.info.join('_'),
        brand: head.brand,
        dID: head.dID,
        price: head.price,
        total: maps.size()
    ]
}
```

The `groupBy()` groups the `Map`s by `dID` producing a `Map<Integer, List<Map<String, Object>>>` like this:

```
[3:[['info':'F123', 'brand':'BMW', 'dID':3, 'price':40000], ['info':'F100', 'brand':'BMW', 'dID':3, 'price':40000], ['info':'F200', 'brand':'BMW', 'dID':3, 'price':40000]], 5:[['info':'C344', 'brand':'mercedes', 'dID':5, 'price':50000], ['info':'C354', 'brand':'mercedes', 'dID':5, 'price':50000]], 7:[['info':'D355', 'brand':'Opel', 'dID':7, 'price':30000]]]
```

It's tough to read, but it's a `Map` where the key is the `bID` and the value a `List` of `Map`s, each `Map` pertaining to a vehicle with the same `bID`. Phew!

Finally, `collect()` builds a new `List` of `Map`s, which looks like this:

```
[['infos':'F123_F100_F200', 'brand':'BMW', 'dID':3, 'price':40000, 'total':3], ['infos':'C344_C354', 'brand':'mercedes', 'dID':5, 'price':50000, 'total':2], ['infos':'D355', 'brand':'Opel', 'dID':7, 'price':30000, 'total':1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact

```
def orginalList= [info:"F123",brand:"BMW",dID:3,price:40000, 
    info:"F100",brand:"BMW",dID:3,price:40000, 
    info:"F200",brand:"BMW",dID:3,price:40000, 
    info:"C344",brand:"mercedes",dID:5,price:50000, 
    info:"C354",brand:"mercedes",dID:5,price:50000, 
    info:"D355",brand:"Opel",dID:7,price:30000]
```

is not a list, but a map, so you override six times each key. So actually you have only:

```
orginalList= [
    info:"D355",brand:"Opel",dID:7,price:30000]
```

Please fix your code basing on this clue...

and remember that you can always use f.e.:

```
def orginalList= [[info:"F123",brand:"BMW",dID:3,price:40000], 
    [info:"F100",brand:"BMW",dID:3,price:40000]]
```

Comment: How can I exract the code can you give example please.

Comment: Show me how does your code now looks like (after using my clues) and where do you have problem?

Comment: I dont understand, I have three BWM with dID 3 and mercedes with dID 5 and one Opel with dID 7, how can do that in the code?